Filterable Field in @ptc-org/nestjs-query-graphql package clash with ConfigService
Given that this DTO works
import { ObjectType, Field } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { FilterableField } from '@ptc-org/nestjs-query-graphql';
import { GraphQLJSONObject } from 'graphql-type-json';
import { AbstractDto } from 'nestjs-dev-utilities';

@ObjectType('User')
export class UserDto extends AbstractDto {
  @Field()
  firstName: string;
}

But When I change the DTO to use FilterableField
export class UserDto extends AbstractDto {
  @FilterableField()
  firstName: string;
}

It return error like
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ConfigService (?, CONFIGURATION(a00e49cf-4f8a-4fdc-a5a8-a4730614c7dd)). Please make sure that the argument Symbol(CONFIG_SERVICE) at index [0] is available in the ConfigModule context.
**Remarks: I've set the ConfigModule, {isGlobal: true}
This is the package version I'm using
 "@ptc-org/nestjs-query-core": "^6.1.3",
 "@ptc-org/nestjs-query-graphql": "^6.1.3",
 "@ptc-org/nestjs-query-typeorm": "^6.1.3",


Did you import the config module as ConfigModule.forRoot(...)?

@Module({   imports: [     ConfigModule.forRoot({       isGlobal: true,       load: [configuration],       validationSchema,     }),   ],   controllers: [],   providers: [],   exports: [], }) export class CoreConfigModule {}
yeaa, I did so in my custom config module and import it in my app.module.ts
imports: [     CoreConfigModule,     UserModule,     TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({       imports: [CoreConfigModule],       inject: [ConfigService],

Perhaps you need to add ConfigModule to the exports of the CoreConfigModule. It's not normally necessary but worth a try since your module definitions look a bit weird — forRoot methods are usually called in \the AppModule.
